# ( Android ) Blank Black Screen on switching to new activity

Tags: android, eclipse, out-of-memory, android-logcat

i am using eclipse and when i run my app , first activity works fine , but as soon as i click a button to start another activity , a blank black screen is all i get on emulator. 
Following is the logcat , appears to be a memory problem , dont know how to deal with it . I tried increasing internal memory to 4 GiB in the avd manager , but still no help.

P.S - second activity accesses database file from internal memory .

### Can anybody Help ?

---

**logcat : -**

02-24 10:50:05.942: W/FileUtils(9321): **Failed to   chmod(/data/data/com.example.quiz/databases/CQuiz): libcore.io.ErrnoException:   chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)**
.
.
02-24 10:51:06.812: E/dalvikvm-heap(9321): **Out of memory on a 529564-byte   allocation.**
.
.
02-24 10:50:06.462: D/dalvikvm(9321): **GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 359K, 13% free   3053K/3476K, paused 74ms, total 108ms**
02-24 10:50:07.592: D/dalvikvm(9321): **GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 4% free   3501K/3632K, paused 83ms, total 84ms**
.
.
02-24 10:51:03.602: I/dalvikvm-heap(9321): **Clamp target GC heap from 48.252MB to 48.000MB**
02-24 10:51:03.602: D/dalvikvm(9321): **GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1034K, 3% free 47300K/48412K, paused 930ms, total 930ms**
.
.
02-24 10:51:06.812: E/dalvikvm-heap(9321): **Out of memory on a 529564-byte allocation.**
.
.
02-24 10:51:06.932: D/AndroidRuntime(9321): **Shutting down VM**
02-24 10:51:06.932: W/dalvikvm(9321): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0xb2a9aba8)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321): **FATAL EXCEPTION: main**
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321): **Process: com.example.quiz, PID: 9321**
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321): **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   com.example.quiz.Andro.onCreate(Andro.java:55)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-24 10:51:06.982: E/AndroidRuntime(9321):     at   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

02-24 10:57:13.152: W/FileUtils(11021): **Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.example.quiz/databases/CQuiz): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)**

2nd Activity : -

```
public class Andro extends ActionBarActivity{
TextView tv;
RadioButton r1,r2,r3,r4;
RadioGroup rg;
Button pre,nex,conf;
MyDatabase md;
Cursor c;
String ans;
protected void onCreate(Bundle b){

super.onCreate(b);
setContentView(R.layout.a_quiz);

tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
r2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
r3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
r4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

pre = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
nex = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
conf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

md= new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext(),"CQuiz",null,1);

c = md.fetch();
c.moveToFirst();
Integer count=c.getColumnCount();
Toast.makeText(this,count.toString()+"columns",3000).show();
while(c.isFirst())
{ 
  tv.setText(c.getString(0));
   r1.setText(c.getString(1));
   r2.setText(c.getString(2));
  r3.setText(c.getString(3));
   r4.setText(c.getString(4));
   }    
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code. But your error is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Without looking at your code it is impossible to know what is causing this. You can also try increasing the heap size in your emulator

Comment: Increasing Heap size worked , changed it to 64 .  Problem Solved :) Thanks

Comment: it worked for once, but now same code run is being unfortunately closed :(  
following continues in logcat -
 
**Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.example.quiz/databases/CQuiz): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)**

02-24 14:03:35.023: D/dalvikvm(1356): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 373K, 13% free 3038K/3476K, paused 196ms, total 238ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a known bug.

Have a look at:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64345 ?

How and where do you create the database?

Comment: i created it using sqlite browser and pushed it in ddms > data > data > myprojectfolder>databases>.....